# merge the value of two objects increasing the value of a key if matched [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, merge, lodash

Given two object:

```
const obj1 = {
  1: 5,
  2: 4
};

const obj2 = {
  1: 10,
  2: 1,
  3: 1
};
```

How do I merge them with [Lodash Merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge) to create the resulting object of:

```
const newObj = {
  1: 15,
  2: 5,
  3: 1
};
```

**What have you tried?** Nothing because I have no idea how to use merge in this way or if merge is the right way.

Comment: Merge is not the right way, it doesn't combine the properties, it just uses one of them.

Comment: @Barmar Can you suggest a proper way (with examples) ?

Comment: Try [`_.assignWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assignWith)

Comment: @Barmar Again I am not understanding how to use this, can you please provide a runnable example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mergeWith) - it has a customizer that enables you to define the how will properties be merged.

```js
const obj1 = {
  1: 5,
  2: 4
};

const obj2 = {
  1: 10,
  2: 1,
  3: 1
};

const result = _.mergeWith({}, obj1, obj2, (o1, o2) => {
  if(_.isNumber(o1)) {
    return o1 + o2;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```